# How do I query an array within a schema in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Really stuck on querying an array nested within a schema.

The list schema looks likes this:

```
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [cardSchema]
});
```

I want to be able to query a particular list for a particular item, and figured this would work:

```
const listId = req.body.listId;
const itemId = req.body.itemId;

List.updateOne({
    "_id": listId
}, {
    $pull: {
        items: {
            "_id": itemId
        }
    }
});
```

As I understand, I'm updating a list by the id of "listId", and then removing something from it. The thing I'm removing is within the "items" array and has the id "itemId". However, this doesn't do anything.

I have a much clumsier, heavy-handed way of getting round this problem, shown here:

```
List.findOne({
    _id: listId
}, function (err, list) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        const listItems = list.items
        listItems.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item._id == itemId) {
                const index = listItems.findIndex(function (i) {
                    return i.id === itemId
                })
                if (index !== -1) listItems.splice(index, 1);
                list.save();
            }
        })
    }
```

But I'd much rather something like the former. The latter just seems ridiculous when nesting arrays within arrays within arrays etc so I know this can't be the sensible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution eventually:

```
List.findOne({listId}, function (err, list) {
    list.items.id(itemId).remove();
    list.save();            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following Schema:

```js
const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [cardSchema]
});
```

and the following ids:

```
const listId = req.body.listId;
const itemId = req.body.itemId;
```

If your final goal is to remove item with `itemId`, I believe the code below should do the trick:

```js
List.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": listId },
    { $pull: { items: { _id: itemId} } },
    { 'new': true }
);
```

The core idea is this:

```js
Collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: yourCollectionId },
    { $pull: { subdocumentsArray: { _id: subdocumentId} } },
    { new: true }
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This hasn't worked though. It doesn't like "item" on line 5, the same line that I don't understand. I figured I ought to replace it with "itemId", but this didn't work either.

Does that line mean "Get items[at the index where _id = itemId]"? I then thought maybe it should be "items.$._id" and some other permeatations but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: If I just use List.find(), I can easily get it to log the right item, but then it won't allow me to use $pull.

Comment: @purpleovskoff I have updated the answer to a working solution. Let me know if that helps! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no, that's back where I started, except for `{ "new" : true }` - I've logged the list before and after this and it is still unchanged. I've also tried setting itemId as `const itemId = 'new ObjectId("' + req.body.itemId + '")'` to match up with how the item._id is actually logged